Reverse Engineering license data
I am currently working on a VB3 project (!) and it's hard to get the licenses for all those old VBX stuff. Finally I want to convert it to 32 bit (VB4 or maybe even VB6) and again I need licenses for OCX files, which are also hard to find.
For me it seems like a grey area: nobody will really be hurt, because making business with VBX and OCX files is obsolete (maybe I'm wrong?) and such information is useful for people working on legacy code projects. On the other hand side, well, it's still the code of that company and probably copyright protected.
Some of the licenses are not too hard to reverse engineer. Would it be ok to post a question and an answer on how to reverse engineer that?
As I can be identified personally by my profile, do you think there's a risk of being brought to court for those pre-year-2000 components?

I am curious what in the world you are doing way back in VB3 code. Man, that is ancient stuff. Where's the value? Some specialized app?

I personally think it's OK to ask and answer. After all, most reversing knowledge doesn't bring any harm to the original developer's business.
And from my experience, as long as people really don't care, no one will risk paying a lawyer to bring you to court, for uncertain gains. But I can't guarantee that, naturally.
